# SAP Custom Workflow is not working (LPOR missing)

Tags: workflow, abap

I created my first custom OO Workflow.

I created the class and added the interface `IF_WORKFLOW`.

I implemented the methods `LPOR` and `FIND_BY_LPOR` of interface `BI_PERSISTENT`.

- The value of `INSTID` should be the Workitem ID.

I just have one activity (dialog) in my workflow. When I'm testing the workflow, an error appears.

> Error-Code WL-821 - Dereferencing NULL-Reference.

I created a breakpoint in my custom `FIND_BY_LPOR` method. There is a CHECK for `LPOR-INSTID` is NOT INITIAL.

Unfortunately my `LPOR-INSTID` is always INITIAL. `LPOR-CATID` and `LPOR-TYPEID` are filled.

Is there something I have to customize?

Code:

- `CONSTRUCTOR` (When is the constructor called, I can't get in while debugging?)

  ```
    m_workitem_id = i_wi_id.

    ms_lpor-catid  = swfco_objtype_cl.
    ms_lpor-typeid = mc_objtype.
    ms_lpor-instid = i_wi_id.
  ```
- `LPOR`

  ```
    result = ms_lpor.
  ```
- `FIND_BY_LPOR`

  ```
    DATA: ls_key      TYPE zs_wf_key,
          ls_instance TYPE ty_instance.

    CLEAR: ls_key, ls_instance.

    CHECK lpor-instid IS NOT INITIAL. "HERE ITS EXITING, BECAUSE INSTID = INITIAL

    READ TABLE mt_instances WITH KEY id = lpor-instid
                            INTO ls_instance.
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      TRY .
          ls_key = lpor-instid.
          CREATE OBJECT ls_instance-instance TYPE (lpor-typeid)
            EXPORTING
              is_key = ls_key.

        CATCH cx_bo_error cx_root 
          RETURN.
      ENDTRY.

      ls_instance-id = lpor-instid.
      APPEND ls_instance TO mt_instances.
    ENDIF.

    result ?= ls_instance-instance.
  ```

Comment: `INSTID` should not be initial. How do you trigger the workflow, how did you initialize `INSTID`?

Comment: I trigger the workflow inside the Workflow Builder with F8. The activity and workflow container have the standard fields, I didn't add any custom fields by the way

Comment: What do you mean with how I initialize INSTID? I just have the code posted in my question. There is no other customizing or something else regarding LPOR

Comment: I also tried creating the Workflow via Event. Unfortunately same error appears. INSTID stays INITIAL

Comment: You say you have one activity, so I guess you have connected it to your class in some way (otherwise there's no reason that SAP instantiates your class). Usually the event is used to pass the object key (including `INSTID`), it's stored as an element in the workflow container, and its value is passed to the activities which are connected to the object, via the "binding".